# Symfony 3 - Using imagecreatefromjpeg in controller gives an error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, php-gd, imagecreatefromjpg

I am using Symfony 3 and when I try to use imagecreatefromjpeg function in PHP it gives the following error.

> Attempted to call function "imagecreatefromjpeg" from namespace
>   "AppBundle\Controller"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `gd` extension installed? Looks like this function doesn't exist in global scope, which is why php attempts to load it from current namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Do you already have enable/installed gd extension? If not, you have to install it. You can add it in composer.json( "ext-gd": "*" )

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\imagecreatefromjpeg` (from global namespace)